# Is there a lightweight M3U editor?

Tags: playlists

I'd like to use an editor to open `.m3u` files, add MP3s, remove them, and at the end save the `.m3u`.

Is there? Opening a playlist of 3000 files with Winamp only for adding a files is too slow!

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: This would work on windows - https://iptvm3ueditor.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use notepad (or other basic text editor: [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/), [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [vim](http://www.vim.org/), etc.) to edit the m3u file.

m3u files are simply text files that direct the media programs to the files to play, and in what order. It won't give you the drag and drop functionality of most media programs that can edit playlists (Winamp, VLC, etc.), but it will let you quickly edit the playlist based on your system setup and how fast it can open a few thousand line text documents (most are pretty quick).

Answer (score 1):

It might also be worth checking out Foobar2000 - it's a very lightweight, aggressively optimised music player which has a very powerful playlist / tagging system.

It's austere at first glance, but is incredibly powerful and efficient. Handy if you need to do drag and drop re-ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use a text editor to edit m3u files. But this leaves you with one problem:

> How to get full paths for hundreds of music files

<sub>(You can use something like `Dir /S /R /B > playlist.txt` and append the content via notepad to your existing `m3u` file.)</sub>

But instead I suggest you use a playlist editor like [M3U Dropper](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/M3U-Dropper.shtml).
Open your existing playlist and use drag & drop to add more music files

[image]

#### The advantages are

- Faster then Foobar / Winamp when handling large playlists
- No extra step needed to get mp3 paths
- Portable